# UITableView within a UIView within UIViewController in iOs Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I want to achieve the following in xcode.

[image: interface]

I have a view controller. Within this `UIViewController` I have a `UITabBar`. Below them is a `UIView`. What is the best way to add a `UITableView` to the `UIView`? Then being able to click on a `UITableViewCell` and opening up another `UIViewController` to show more information about the `UITableViewCell`?

Here is the current setup of my storyboard:

[image: Current Storyboard]

Could you offer me a solution to this problem? Thanks

Comment: try http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/

Comment: and for custom cell try http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Answer (score 1):

You need a solution to your problem but I'm not sure what your problem is.

In storyboard, drag a `UIView` in your `UIViewController`. Then drag a `UITableView` (not controller) in that `UIVIew`.

You'll be able to see the view hierarchy on the left.

Then link your tableview `datasource` and `delegate` to the parent controller.

in your .h file, add the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols, also link your tableview as an `Outlet`.

In your .m files, add the tableview delegate methods (`numberOfRowsInSection:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`)

I also suggest adding `didSelect:` among the tableview methods because, well, you'll need it.

and you're good to go. :)

It's actually the EXACT same thing as creating a tableview, except that your tableview is a subview of a UIView, which doesn't matter at all if it comes to code. The only thing you'll have to be "careful" of is to build your view properly in storyboard, and make sure the constraints don't make your tableview unusable for some reason.

Check [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29920901/3603502) where I explain how to make a tableview and make it load another controller while passing data, which is something you might need if everything I wrote here still confuses you.

**FOLLOW UP:**

From your comments I understand that this subview of your UIView can be different things ; a tableview, a webview, and so on.

There are many ways to do that, and from my little knowledge I see two that can be easy and reliable (from my <1year experience as a developer...).

1. Get all the possibilities ready in your parent viewcontroller, if you only have 2 possibilities for example, that's "okay".
2. The best way is to prepare a container view (it's literally called container view) which would load different OTHER view controllers according to your needs.

I think option 2 is more reliable, because it will split the code into different classes, will allow you to modify each of them independently, and you can easily remove/add new views.

To my knowledge, you'll have some kind of switch statement in your parent controller that will load the desired UIViewController (or tableview or anything). Whatever you do there will just be as usual, but constricted to a smaller view inside another VC.

You can create that container view in storyboard and pre-link every other VC with segues (ToTable, ToWeb, ToCollection) are good examples for segue names that would link that container view to your 3 UIViewControllers.

Note that you can pass data if need be, but you would have all the separate controllers handle their own stuff even though it is visible inside your current vc.

Comment: Reading through this answer sounds great. But i've one thing that has an affect on the whole reason why i'm doing this. The UIView that you say drag a UITableView into needs to be dynamic. Depending on a previous cell selection. The UIView must either load a UIWebView or this UITableView. What are your thoughts? Is there a way to do this so I can incorporate both objects?

Comment: Oh so you have to create both views (the UIView and the Webview/Tableview/whatever) in code, it is *slightly* more complicated, but nothing unreasonable.

You'll have to master the art of CGRect & frames, let me edit my answer quickly

Comment: I thought it was possible to create the views in the storyboard.. and then kind of load them into another view? Is this not possible? This is my first app... a bit complicated already haha

Comment: Oh if this is your first app I strongly suggest what I just added to my answer :D Unless you're already experienced with other languages or mobiles platforms.
But if you feel strong enough and motivated enough, I think you should be able to complete what i've said in about 8 hours top, considering you'll have to read at least 3 different tutorials, do them, and then mix it all.

Comment: I've created the app with android.. It works... But the coding style is obviously different and it's taking me a while to adapt. What are these tutorials? The text you've posted or .. do you have any links to share.. thanks for the help. Will give you an update once i've got my head around what I need to do!

Comment: Yeah i'll give you some links and come back when you're all done with that if you're still struggling.
Here a simple tableview tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

And i haven't seen this one but apparently it's a really good video for VC containment : https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102

Here is the code package of that video : https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_sample_code/wwdc_2012_session_code.dmg

Comment: From there you can create your tableview in another VC and make your container view "read" that VC. Then you'd have to decide (by yourself) how that container decides which VC  to load. I  guess that's just a couple of if's or a switch in the viewdidload according to some of the user choices that are irrelevant here.

Comment: This project was also linked https://github.com/toolmanGitHub/stackedViewControllers
And could be of some use :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return [catagorry count];    //count number of row from counting array hear cataGorry is An Array
    }



    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                               reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
            }

            // Here we use the provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
            // Ensure you use a placeholder image otherwise cells will be initialized with no image
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/image.jpg"]
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
                cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
            return cell;
        }
```

these are the basic method to create a basic table view. to load an view controller corresponing to the cell click u can use did select row method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{



    /*   //Pushing next view 
        cntrSecondViewController *cntrinnerService = [[cntrSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"cntrSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:cntrinnerService animated:YES];
*/

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self];
}
```